# Unable to send data to Firebase in a back ground service

Tags: java, android, firebase, service, location

Sending data to the Firebase but unable to send, my service crash but application still running and when I remove the Firebase code, service runs correctly.

I just want to upload the data to the Firebase with the current location. Every thing is working perfect but Firebase is not sending data to the database but it works with the same code in the activity.

Starting service,

```
public class location_service extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 50000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;
    DatabaseReference databasecustomer;
    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
    {
        Location mLastLocation;


        public LocationListener(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {

            Log.e("onLocationChanged: " ,"");
            mLastLocation.set(location);
            String lats= "s";
            String lngs= "s";
            databasecustomer= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Labor");
            String id= databasecustomer.push().getKey();
            send_request send_request=new send_request(id,lats,lngs);
            databasecustomer.child(id).setValue(send_request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is my toast message"+id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of the security of database in firebase, change the rule of your database to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

- make sure that your android studio is connected to firebase and to firebase database